# How to access data from Document Snapshot in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have items in Firestore I am retrieving using this method

```dart
class EntriesList extends StatefulWidget {
  const EntriesList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EntriesListState createState() => _EntriesListState();
}

class _EntriesListState extends State<EntriesList> {
  final Stream _entryStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
      .snapshots();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _entryStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        // this is where I am getting my error
        return ListView(children: snapshot.data.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                   Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                   return Text(data['text'])
               }
            )
         );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am essentially trying to get the data from my snapshot but it is instead return an instance of `_JsonDocumentSnapshot`. I am unsure of how to get my data from here.

Following this guide on how to get items from Firestore
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Comment: Duplicate Question, found my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788549/using-stream-building-with-a-specific-firestore-document

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing here is that json snapshot needs to be decoded before accessing the data as a Map. An [object](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#create-an-album-class) can be created to map the data from Firestore.

As an example, you can create an object for the 'text' data.

```dart
class YourData {
  String text;

  YourData(
      {required this.text});

  factory YourData.fromJson(
      {required Map<dynamic, dynamic> json}) {
    return YourData(
      text: text,
    );
  }
}
```

This data can then be mapped with

```dart
snapshot.data.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
  YourData yourData = YourData.fromJson(
    json: document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
  print('${yourData.text}');
});
```