# How do i retrieve data from firebase store by document in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

How do I retrieve data from the firebase store by a document not a collection in a flutter as a DataRow and DataCell? For example, this image below.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I want to retrieve the data only in the Teabags document but I don't know how please help.

this is an example of my code using collections.

```
Widget buildDataTable() {
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Products')
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Something went wrong! ${snapshot.error}');
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final columns = ['Items', 'Price'];
        return DataTable(
            columnSpacing: 300,
            showCheckboxColumn: false,
            columns: getcolumns(columns),
            rows: _createRows(snapshot.data));
      } else {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    });
  }

 List<DataColumn> getcolumns(List<String> columns) => columns
  .map((String column) => DataColumn(
      label: Text(column, style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)))
  .toList();
 List<DataRow> _createRows(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
List<DataRow> newList = snapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

  return DataRow(
    cells: [
      DataCell(Text(data['Items'].toString(),
          style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
      DataCell(Text(data['Price'].toString(),
          style: Defaults.drawerTextBlacknormal)),
    ],
    onSelectChanged: ((bool? selected) =>
        selected == null ? selected = false : selected = true),
  );
}).toList();
return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line will return the stream of the **document** with id *Teabags*:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Products").doc("Teabags").snapshots()
```

You were missing the "`.doc("{id}")`" function.

You should be able to retrieve the data in the following way:

```
String items = snapshot.data()["Items"];
int price = snapshot.data()["Price"];
```

[Similar question has been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788549/using-stream-building-with-a-specific-firestore-document)